# Parse and combine many xml files, insufficient memory

Tags: php, xml, symfony, optimization, memory-leaks

Can you help me please with ideas to be able to parse and combine about 12 xml files, each file has ~ 5 mega, to finally have a single global file.

Currently, I use a cron to run a script (a symfony framework command)

For each file I deserialize it with the bundle JMSSerializerBundle, it allows to create an object from an xml file.

And I have a memory problem. I think this is due to this deserialization.

So my questions are,

- Do you know a better way to do this stup, if I replace this deserialization with this bundle by a parsing with SimpleXML, do you think it consumes less memory ?
- Also, if I save the files in variables Redis does it change anything ?
- And, a last question, if I use the database, for example, I save the files in a table, then I retrieve all the records in a table and with this I build the global xml file, can it be a good idea?
  Or build the global file in several steps (with 3 files each time), saving it each time in a table and retrieve data each time in simple array.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you're having memory issues with SimpleXML, you should probably switch to using a pull parser like [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php)

Comment: A combination of XMLReader and XMLWriter should be able to allow you to build the whole file in one go.  This depends on the amount of processing you have to do with the data in the mean time, you may be able to pipeline them both in one go.

Comment: Yep i am going to use XMLReader thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one of-task that is done via the command line you might be able to get away with setting PHP's `memory_limit` to `-1` using `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` in the beginning of your CLI-script.

This is obviously not an option for requests as a single request could hog all the system's memory. Also note that you are obviously still bound by your available system memory, so you might still run into this issue.

As already suggested in the comments you might be able to reduce the memory usage by using a pull parser like [XMLReader](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php). That will reduce the amount of memory used up by reading the XML, but obviously keeping the read data (probably in an array) will still accumulate. If you are not using the latest PHP version, then this is probably the easiest way to optimize memory usage there.

Other than that I recommend using a tool like xhprof or blackfire.io to profile the memory usage of your script and try to fix the main problems pointed out by them.